# How to create youtube iframe code using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, youtube

I have problem that iframe code is not allowed in IFTTT so need to improwise current javascript in which manner that html code dont need to add iframe tag.

Find my current youtube iframe script,

```js
$("[data-media]").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    var videoUrl = $this.attr("data-media");
    var popup = $this.attr("href");
    var $popupIframe = $(popup).find("iframe");
    
    $popupIframe.attr("src", videoUrl);
    
    $this.closest(".page").addClass("show-popup");
});

$(".popup").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    
    $(".page").removeClass("show-popup");
});

$(".popup > iframe").on("click", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
html,
body {
    margin:0; padding:0; height:100%;
}
p {
    margin:0;
}
.page {
    position: relative;
    height:100%;
}

.popup {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:2;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    opacity:0;
    visibility:hidden;
    transition:.3s ease;
}

.show-popup .popup {
    opacity:1;
    visibility: visible;    
}

.popup > iframe {
    position:absolute;
    top:50px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-280px;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
    <p><a href="#media-popup" data-media="//www.youtube.com/embed/YoXa2Pl7Hk0">click me</a></p>
    
    <div class="popup" id="media-popup">
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried to improvise using following blog reference but not succeed,
Blog reference url: http://www.labnol.org/internet/light-youtube-embeds/27941/

My final goal is remove iframe tag from HTML without disturbing current output.

Comment: Are you able to use `embed` or `object` tags? [check here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_youtube.asp)

Comment: I tried but embed and object tags also not allowed in IFTTT so using http://www.labnol.org/internet/light-youtube-embeds/27941/ we can recode in manner that iframe tag will removed from my HTML code without disturbing current functionality.

Comment: @Varinder,@Ergec,I need to remove iframe tag from html code, I tried to mixup with your jfiddle scripts of both of you but not succeed ,please check following links, 1.http://jsfiddle.net/Varinder/WkyPc/1/   2.http://jsfiddle.net/kf6sff00/4/